# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user3' when getting Django object by field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I've been getting this error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user3' " when I try to retrieve an object from FacebookProfile.

It doesn't give any error when getting by id or any int datatype.

```
def index(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_username = str(current_user.username)
    fbuser=FacebookProfile.objects.get(user__exact = current_username)
    iden=fbuser.access_token
    facebook = OpenFacebook(iden)
    info = facebook.get('me')
    html = "info: %s" % info
    output = html + 'current_user.username:  ' + current_user.username
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/josephtang/Dropbox/Code/SocialORD/ORDapp/views.py" in index
  40.   leme=FacebookProfile.objects.get(user__exact = current_username)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  298.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  590.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  608.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1198.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1232.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1122.                                                      lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in get_lookup_constraint
  1105.                      value[index]), AND)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/tree.py" in add
  104.         data = self._prepare_data(data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in _prepare_data
  79.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in prepare
  352.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  369.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  613.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /ORDapp/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
fbuser=FacebookProfile.objects.get(user__exact = current_username)
```

with

```
fbuser=FacebookProfile.objects.get(user=current_user.id)
```

Or if you want to use the current_username

```
fbuser=FacebookProfile.objects.get(user__username__exact=current_username)
```

Comment: I got the same error as before though. I suspect it has something to do with it expecting an int. I just don't know how to make it not expect an int.

Comment: The third line worked. Could you explain what user__username__exact is? Much appreciated

Comment: It's basically saying to use the `User` model's `username` field for comparison. The additional `__exact` means that the username must match the parameter.